# Convex optimization

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization

I am playing with some Compressed Sensing (think single pixel camera) applications and would like to have a Mathematica equivalent of a Matlab package call Convex Optimization (CVX). Specifically, I am solving an underdetermined, constrained, L1Norm minimization problem. I have been using NMinimize, but it very slow compared to the Matlab code written by a colleague. I don’t want to give him the pleasure of thinking Matlab is superior.  I am sure that the long run times are due to my poor programing skills.  The solution is sparse but I do not know how to add that as an additional constraint.  Anyway, seems I can’t find a good reference for compressed sensing in Mathematica.  Any suggestions would be great!

As an example two data sets

### 1D

```
coef = Transpose[RandomReal[#, 7] & /@ {1, 10 Pi, 2 Pi}];
f[t_] = Total[(#[[1]] Sin[#[[2]] t + #[[3]]]) & /@ coef];
data1d = Table[f[t], {t, 0, 10, 0.01}];
```

Sample obtained using

```
RandomSample[data1d,n1]
```

### 2D

```
data2d = ImageData[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Boat"}]];
```

1 pixel random sampling

```
Total[RandomSample[#, 256] & /@ data2d, 2]
```

I hope the 200 reputation points  bounty don't go to waste.

Comment: For a convex optimization problem `FindMinimum` is likely to be much faster than `NMinimize`.

Comment: @rhermans I know you won't get pinged, but since you seem interested in this, consider editing the question to add your own example signal and re-sample. While I probably won't be able to solve the problem, others might be more tempted to try if they had an example that *you* chose for its properties. I think such an edit would be within the SE guidelines for editing others' questions.

Comment: And don't forget to wrap `Parallelize[]` around your code.  This is a highly parallelizable operation.  You can be even faster if you explicitly split your iterations and such into the number of your processors.

Comment: FWIW, the Matlab CVX package is open-source: http://cvxr.com/cvx/

Comment: There is a Mathematica package for L1-minimization called **[L1Packv2](http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3728)**

Comment: Can you post, what you already tried (the `NMinimize`-approach) and some timing comparisons, so as to know what we are up against?

Comment: @rhermans I assume the examples are yours. If so, I cannot say anything unless you post some code, as I have no idea what it is you are attempting to optimize. (If you don't wish to edit someone else's question, could post it as a new one. Done correctly, it would have sufficiently more info that it would not be regarded as a duplicate.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, Thanks for your comment. The things is that I think I don't understand enough about how to implement Compressed Sensing to even make a well structured question. I was wishing to reproduce something similar to [this paper](http://www.pnas.org/cgi/content/long/109/35/13928)

Comment: @rhermans Okay, that paper appears to be informative, I'll have a look. I'd still recommend you try to put together a question indicating a sample input and desired result (or at least a clear description of what would comprise a viable result), if at all possible.

Comment: Can you please define `t` and `n1` in your code?

Comment: The paper mentioned is about *equidistant* time-scale-measurements, for which *equidistant* frequency measurements are desired. The number of time-scale-measurements is to be minimized.

The restriction "*equidistant*" does **not** match the question here.

I am confused.

Answer (score 23):

> I am playing with some Compressed Sensing (think single pixel camera) applications and would like to have a Mathematica equivalent of a Matlab package call Convex Optimization (CVX). [...] very slow compared to the Matlab code written by a colleague. I don’t want to give him the pleasure of thinking Matlab is superior

[CVX](http://cvxr.com/bio/) is the result of years of [theoretical and applied research](http://cvxr.com/about/), a book on [convex optimization](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) and a [company](http://cvxr.com/about/) focused on researching, developing and supporting convex optimization tools. You simply cannot create a *Mathematica* clone overnight that parallels the performance and features of CVX, and certainly not via a question on Stack Exchange! :)

There are plenty (way more than you'll ever need!) of examples with code for doing compressed sensing/L1 optimizations in MATLAB for different constraints and your best bet would be to leverage those existing scripts.

### Use CVX via MATLink

The best way to do convex optimization (beyond what `NMinimize` and friends allow you) in *Mathematica* **if you also have a MATLAB license** is to use CVX via MATLink. In fact, I co-wrote it with Szabolcs specifically because I personally needed to use CVX + *Mathematica*.

As an example workflow of using CVX with *Mathematica*, we can solve this [convex optimization problem](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/examples/cvxbook/Ch06_approx_fitting/html/fig6_19.html) as follows:

```
MEvaluate["
    n = 6;
    m = 40;
    randn('state',0);

    % generate 50 ponts ui, vi
    u = linspace(-1,1,m);
    v = 1./(5+40*u.^2) + 0.1*u.^3 + 0.01*randn(1,m);

    A = vander(u');
    A = A(:,m-n+[1:n]);     

    % L-infty fit
    cvx_begin quiet
       variable x_inf(n)
       minimize (norm(A*x_inf - v', inf))
    cvx_end
"]
```

CVX is quite verbose and it is a bit more efficient to use `quiet` when running it via MATLink. There are other CVX global variables (starting with `cvx_`) that you can use to programmatically check which solver was used, whether the problem was solved or if it is infeasible, etc. rather than relying on the textual output. If you are doing active algorithm development using CVX, then it might be better to use MATLAB directly for this part and then use MATLink once you are satisfied and have frozen the routine.

Next, we transfer the optimal solution and the original quantities to *Mathematica* using `MGet`:

```
{u, v, A, xinf} = MGet[{"u", "v", "A", "x_inf"}];
```

Finally, we compute the optimal $L_2$ norm solution in *Mathematica*, construct the polynomial using Horner's method and plot them in *Mathematica*:

```
With[{hornerPoly = Function[{var, x}, Fold[# var + #2 &, x]]},
    Show[
        ListPlot[Transpose@{u, v}, PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[5], Gray}],
        Plot[{hornerPoly[x, x2], hornerPoly[x, xinf]}, {x, -1, 1}, Evaluated -> True,
            PlotLegends -> {"!(*SubscriptBox[(L), (2)])",  "!(*SubscriptBox[(L), ([Infinity])])"}]
    ]
]
```

### Compressed sensing/Sparse representations in *Mathematica*

If you don't have access to MATLAB, then you'll have to implement the algorithms yourself. You'll find `NMinimize` thoroughly lacking when you want to implement $\ell_1$ minimization *and* enforce sparsity or do $\ell_p$ minimizations for $p < 1$, etc. There's no magic way around actually learning the theory behind sparse representations yourself, learning the standard algorithms which are the building blocks to developing more sophisticated algorithms for your specific problem, understanding standard computational tricks to enforce sparsity, restricted isometry property, etc. I can recommend the following books which I found quite helpful:

- ["Sparse and Redundant Representations — From Theory to Applications in Signal and Image Processing"](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-1-4419-7010-7), M. Elad, Springer 2010
- ["Compressed Sensing: Theory and Applications"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107005582), Y. C. Eldar & G. Kutyniok, Cambridge University Press 2012

Not to leave you completely in the dark, here are my implementations of a few basic pursuit algorithms (written for version 9). Also note that I did not write this (2-3 years old at this point) with the intent of sharing with others or as an expository piece of code, so it might be quite cryptic but reasonably idiomatic. Nevertheless, they're based on the pseudocode in Chapter 3 of Elad's book, so if you're using that, you might be able to follow.

#### [Matching Pursuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pursuit)

```
MatchingPursuit[A_?MatrixQ, b_, epsilon_] := Module[
    {solution, residual},

    solution[] = ConstantArray[0, Last@Dimensions@A];
    solution[z_] := With[
        {pos = First@Position[z, Max@z]},
        solution[] = ReplacePart[solution[], pos -> First@(solution[][[ pos ]] + 
            Transpose[A[[;;, pos]]].residual[])];
        pos
    ];

    residual[] = b;
    residual[pos_] := residual[] = residual[] - (A[[;;, pos]].Transpose@A[[;;, pos]]).residual[];

    Sow@NestWhile[Composition[residual,solution,Abs[Transpose@A.#]&], b, Flatten@#.Flatten@# > epsilon&];
    solution[] // Chop
]
```

#### [Iteratively Re-weighted Least Squares (IRLS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares)

```
IRLS[A_?MatrixQ, b_, epsilon_, p_:1] := NestWhile[
    Composition[
        DiagonalMatrix@SparseArray@Flatten@Abs@#^p&, 
        #.Transpose@A.PseudoInverse[A.#.Transpose@A].b&, 
        #.#&],
    Last@Dimensions@A ~IdentityMatrix~ SparseArray,
    Sow@Norm[#-#2] > epsilon&, 2
]["NonzeroValues"] // Chop
```

#### Orthogonal Matching Pursuit

```
OrthogonalMatchingPursuit[A_?MatrixQ, b_, epsilon_] := Module[
    {support,residual},

    support[] = {};
    support[z_] := support[] = Flatten@Sort[support[] ~Join~ First@Position[z, Max@z]];

    residual := With[{AS = A[[;;,#]]}, b - (AS.PseudoInverse@AS).b]&;

    Sow@NestWhile[Composition[residual,support,Abs[Transpose@A.#]&], b, Flatten@#.Flatten@# > epsilon&];
    SparseArray[Thread[# -> Flatten[PseudoInverse@A[[;; , #]].b] &@support[]], Last@Dimensions@A] // Normal // Chop
]
```

Finally, here's a little snippet showing that each of these algorithms recover the sparse solution (again, these might make more sense if you're following Elad's book, but nevertheless):

```
SparseRandomVector[n_Integer,k_Integer] /; k < n := RandomSample[Table[RandomReal[], {k}] ~Join~ ConstantArray[0, n-k], n]
RandomMatrix[n_Integer,m_Integer] := RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {n,m}]
NormalizeColumns[mat_?MatrixQ] := Normalize /@ Transpose[mat] // Transpose

SeedRandom[1234];
{#, MatrixForm@With[{A = NormalizeColumns@RandomMatrix[20, 40], 
       x = SparseRandomVector[40, 2], tol = 10^-4}, {x, #[A, A.x, tol]}]
 } & /@ {MatchingPursuit, OrthogonalMatchingPursuit, IRLS} // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the remark on lacking l_1 optimization. That's linear programming. Do you mean handling of linear constraints with nonlinear objective (or vice versa)?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The remark included the clause following it — "and enforce sparsity". `NMinimize` handles $\ell_1$ minimization fine. In compressive sensing/sparse theory, one _wishes_ to solve an $\ell_0$ minimization problem, but because that is NP-hard, you do $\ell_p,\ 0<p\le 1$ minimization under certain assumptions/conditions and with other possibly non-linear constraints. I guess my phrasing wasn't the best way to put it but nothing better comes to mind now... will update it if I think of something better.

Comment: Okay. I was aware that l_1 was being used as a surrogate for l_0 for the problem at hand. It was the "with other possibly non-linear constraints" part I was missing. Makes sense now.

Comment: These codes were really useful(esp matching pursuit) and worked really fast and out of the box - thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the bounty, @gpap :)

Answer (score 2):

Since Mathematica Version 12, 2019, one can use `Fit[{m,v},FitRegularization->{"L1",weight}]` to find a vector `x` that minimizes `Norm[m.x-v,2]^2 + weight*Norm[x,1]`.

**Example.** Here is an adaptation of an example [in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html):

```
(* sparse signal *)
signal = Normal[SparseArray[{134->0.2,330->-0.5,538->0.9,642->0.3,
                             663->0.9,769->0.1,898->0.6},1000]];

(* sampling *)
SeedRandom[1];
designMatrix = With[{m=200},RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1/m],{m,1000}]];
samples = designMatrix.signal;
```

Plot of the sparse signal:

[image]

Here is a sparse reconstruction of the signal, given only the design matrix and the samples:

```
weight = 0.001;
reconstructionFit = Fit[{designMatrix,samples},FitRegularization->{"L1",weight}];
```

We can also reconstruct using matching pursuit given in [the other answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73534/85954):

```
threshold = 0.0001; 
reconstructionMP = SparseArray[MatchingPursuit[designMatrix,samples,threshold]];
```

In this example, both `reconstructionFit` and `reconstructionMP` have exactly $7$ nonzero entries.
Let us compare the results, also to understand that these two algorithms achieve different things:

```
error[rec_,weight_] := Norm[designMatrix.rec-samples,2]^2+weight*Norm[rec,1];

error[reconstructionFit,0]
(* 0.000297385 *)

error[reconstructionMP,0]
(* 0.0000999824 *)

error[reconstructionFit,weight]
(* 0.00320209 *)

error[reconstructionMP,weight]
(* 0.00325481 *)
```

**Discussion.** Here `reconstructionMP` wins with vanishing weight, the error is just below our `threshold` because it is designed to bring the `Norm[...,2]^2`-error below the threshold. And `reconstructionFit` wins for the regularized problem, because that is exactly what is does by definition, even though `reconstructionMP` is also quite good there. In terms of speed, `Fit` is much faster here, but of course, a fair comparison would require an optimized or compiled implementation of matching pursuit.

See also [this](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/convex-optimization/basis-pursuit.html) discussion of basis pursuit.

Comment: Btw, I think there is a "mistake" in the [`Fit` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v13/ref/Fit.html): It claims that the default setting for `NormFunction` is `Norm`, but I think it is actually `Norm[#]^2&`. Usually there is no difference of course, but there is a difference when a `FitRegularization` is included, and one can use this to check that the default is `NormFunction->(Norm[#]^2&)`.