Inverse of UnitDimensions[]
Is there a straightforward way to write an inverse of UnitDimensions to get the SI unit from dimensions?
For example,
inverseUnitDimensions[{{"LengthUnit", 1}, {"MassUnit", 1}, {"TimeUnit", -2}}]

should return "Newtons".

Slightly off-topic: Here's an automatic "unit simplifier" solution: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211950/26598: unitSimplify[Quantity[1, "Meters" "Kilograms"/"Seconds"^2], Join[SIbase, SIderived]] returns {Quantity[1, "Newtons"]} as desired.

You can use QuantityVariableCanonicalUnit:
QuantityVariableCanonicalUnit[QuantityVariable[
  {{"LengthUnit", 1}, {"MassUnit", 1}, {"TimeUnit", -2}}]]
(* ("Kilograms" "Meters")/("Seconds")^2 *)

Now you need a combination of UnitSimplify and UnitConvert:
QuantityUnit[UnitConvert[UnitSimplify[Quantity[1, %]], "SI"]]
(* "Newtons" *)


Thanks.  That's just what I hoped for.  I wish Wolfram documentation would make better use of "See Also."  The first time I saw QuantityVariableCanonicalUnit[] was in your answer.

Using answer from Domen:
In[16]
si[dimensions_]:=
 UnitSimplify[
  UnitConvert[
   QuantityVariableCanonicalUnit[
    QuantityVariable[dimensions]],
   "SI"]]

si[{{"LengthUnit", 1}, {"MassUnit", 1}, {"TimeUnit", -2}}]
si[{{"ElectricCurrentUnit", 1}, {"TimeUnit", 1}}]

Out[17]= Quantity[1, "Newtons"]

Out[18]= Quantity[1, "Coulombs"]

